# Is there an sf (or df) based alternative to kernelUD to estimate bivariate normal kernel density?

Tags: r, r-sp, adehabitathr

I am switching from sp to sf but have some analysis which uses `kernelUD` from `adehabitatHR` which requires my data to be `SpatialPoints`. Is there an equivalent which does not use `sp`, perhaps instead using `sf` or a regular dataframe, which offers similar bandwidth options?

A snippet of my original code using Genetta genetta as an example:

```
library(adehabitatHR)

G_genetta <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0.5519758, 0.27524548,
                                    0.5725632, 0.12309273,
                                    0.5547747, 0.06100429,
                                    0.6110925, 0.16211416,
                                    0.5951087, 0.09316814,
                                    0.5333567, 0.11673812,
                                    0.5855461, 0.11170616,
                                    0.5221387, 0.11061583,
                                    0.5848452, 0.17213175), 
                                  ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

mask_xy_grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01))
coordinates(mask_xy_grid) <- ~ x + y
gridded(mask_xy_grid) <- TRUE

ade_G_genetta <- kernelUD(SpatialPoints(G_genetta), 
                          h = "href", 
                          grid = mask_xy_grid, 
                          kern = "bivnorm")

plot(ade_G_genetta)
```

I am aware of the `ks` package which I could use as follows:

```
library(ks)

mask_xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01)))

kde_G_genetta <- kde(G_genetta,
                     eval.points = mask_xy)

# lazily get comparable plot
kde_G_genetta <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = kde_G_genetta$eval.points, 
                                        data = data.frame(est = kde_G_genetta$estimate))

plot(kde_G_genetta)
```

but this doesn't offer the same bandwidth options as `kernelUD`. I particularly don't understand why `kernelUD` takes a single scalar value for "h" whereas `kde` takes a matrix when they are both applied to a multivariate problem. `kde` also doesn't seem to cope well with limited sampling points, e.g. Alcelaphus buselaphus which gives the error:

```
Error in chol.default(S) : 
  the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite
```

```
A_buselaphus <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0.5109837, 0.1247711,
                                       0.5109837, 0.1247711,
                                       0.5893287, 0.1613403,
                                       0.5893287, 0.1613403,
                                       0.5893287, 0.1613403), 
                                     ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

# using kernelUD
ade_A_buselaphus <- kernelUD(SpatialPoints(A_buselaphus), 
                             h = "href", 
                             grid = mask_xy_grid, 
                             kern = "bivnorm")

plot(ade_A_buselaphus)

# using kde
kde_A_buselaphus <- kde(A_buselaphus,
                        eval.points = mask_xy)

# lazily get comparable plot
kde_A_buselaphus <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = kde_A_buselaphus$eval.points, 
                                           data = data.frame(est = kde_A_buselaphus$estimate))

plot(kde_A_buselaphus)
```

I could use MASS, but I run into the same bandwidth problem as it takes a "vector of bandwidths for x and y directions":

```
library(MASS)

mask.xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01)))

MASS_G_genetta <- kde2d(G_genetta$V1,
                        G_genetta$V2,
                        n = c(100, 100),
                        lims = c(range(mask.xy$x), range(mask.xy$y)))

# lazily get comparable plots
MASS_G_genetta <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = mask.xy, 
                                         data = data.frame(est = melt(MASS_G_genetta$z)$value))

plot(MASS_G_genetta)

# same axis
plot(ade_G_genetta, zlim = c(0,75))
plot(kde_G_genetta, zlim = c(0,75))
plot(MASS_G_genetta, zlim = c(0,75))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some digging into the source code of `kernelUD` I have found a tolerable, albeit incomplete, solution. I have only been looking within documentation and source code which relates to a bivariate normal kernel using the ad hoc method for calculating `h`.

To find the solution I followed a trail of functions within the CRAN repo:
`kernelUD` -> `.kernelUDs` -> `void kernelhr` -> `void epa`

which led me to this comment within the epa function:
`/* Keep only the points no further than 4*fen of the current pixel */`

`fen` equates to `h` which according to the documentation is by default calculated with:
[image]

for a bivariate normal kernel. I can write this generically as follows:
`(sqrt(0.5*(var(species_xy[[1]]) + var(species_xy[[2]]))))*(nrow(species_xy)^-(1/6))`

Since `kde2d` from `MASS` takes a scalar vector, I can supply it with h*4 for each dimension. The solution for Genetta genetta would therefore be:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(MASS)

# using adehabitatHR
G_genetta <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0.5519758, 0.27524548,
                                    0.5725632, 0.12309273,
                                    0.5547747, 0.06100429,
                                    0.6110925, 0.16211416,
                                    0.5951087, 0.09316814,
                                    0.5333567, 0.11673812,
                                    0.5855461, 0.11170616,
                                    0.5221387, 0.11061583,
                                    0.5848452, 0.17213175), 
                                  ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

mask_xy_grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01))
coordinates(mask_xy_grid) <- ~ x + y
gridded(mask_xy_grid) <- TRUE

ade_G_genetta <- kernelUD(SpatialPoints(G_genetta), 
                          h = "href", 
                          grid = mask_xy_grid, 
                          kern = "bivnorm")

plot(ade_G_genetta)

# using MASS
mask.xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01), y = seq(0.01, 1, by = 0.01)))

H <- (sqrt(0.5*(var(G_genetta[[1]]) + var(G_genetta[[2]]))))*(nrow(G_genetta)^-(1/6))

MASS_G_genetta <- kde2d(G_genetta$V1,
                        G_genetta$V2,
                        n = c(100, 100),
                        h = c(H*4, H*4),
                        lims = c(range(mask.xy$x), range(mask.xy$y)))

# lazily get comparable plots
MASS_G_genetta <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = mask.xy, 
                                         data = data.frame(est = melt(MASS_G_genetta$z)$value))

plot(MASS_G_genetta)

# to confirm this is the same h as the kernelUD output:
kde_G_genetta@h[["h"]]
H
kde_G_genetta@h[["h"]] == H
```

The exact values in the output differ minorly, presumably due to differences in precision between the two methods. A quick summary of the two objects shows us they are functionally the same and backs up the similarity in their plots.

```
summary(kde_G_genetta@data[["ud"]]
summary(MASS_G_genetta$est)
```